# Assune A,B,C,D are sets such that $|A |= |B |$ and $|C |= |D |$. Show that $|C^A |= |D^B |$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Assume $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are sets such that  $|A|= |B |$ and  $|C |= |D |$. Show that  $|C^A |$= $|D^B |$,where $C^A$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $C$, and $D^B$ is the set of all functions from $B$ to $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:C\rightarrow D$ bijections. Define $F:C^A\rightarrow D^B$ as
$$
F(h):=g\circ h\circ f^{-1}
$$
**Edit:** As $A$ and $B$ has the same cardinality, then exists a bijection $f$ between them. In the same form you conclude that $g$ exists.

Now, we need to prove that $F$ is a bijection:

**$F$ is one to one:** Let $h,h'\in C^A$ such that $F(h)=F(h')$ so,
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
g\circ h\circ f^{-1} & = & g\circ h'\circ f^{-1}\\
g^{-1}\circ g\circ h\circ f^{-1}\circ f & = &g^{-1}\circ g\circ h'\circ f^{-1}\circ f\\
h & = & h'
\end{array}
$$
**F is onto:** Let $h\in D^B$. Is easy to see that $g^{-1}\circ h\circ f:A\rightarrow C$ and $F(g^{-1}\circ h\circ f)=h$.

With this, we have that $|C^A|=|D^B|$.

Comment: could you expand and explain why this function works, I am so confused about the cardinality and want to get some inspiration，thx

Comment: @godel you can improve this answer by explaining the link between bijections and sets having equal cardnality.

Comment: @ZhenqingXu See my edit.